# Are anime movies more directly profitable for studios?

Tags: anime-production

Do more of the profits from an anime movie go directly to the studio than a TV series?

I was looking to know if it was more profitable to produce movies over series. I figured they wouldn't have any direct returns unless they own the entire distribution chain so I was curious if the cut taken from the two different distribution chains incentivized movies over series. By studio I meant studios like Ufotable or Shaft.

Comment: Every production has it's own production committee, the staff, resources, and budget can vary drastically. Typically movies have a higher budget on average, but there have been the inverse (high profile, in series ad placement). While it's true that ticket sales are a better overall direct return. Most of the profits of how successful a production is based of disc sales. 3DCG anime productions are more streamline these days compared to hand drawn productions and have a factor in overall profitability when factoring labor and turnaround time. The advent of streaming services might change things